# Uber RideRequestButton not displaying estimates for countries other than US

Tags: android, uber-api

I'm trying to add the `RideRequestButton` feature to my android app, I want it to update the estimates through the button but for some reason this only displays when I use US-related addresses/coordinates.

Is this only supported in US?

Here's my code:

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RideRequestButton requestButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        // Colombia
//        RideParameters rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
//                .setPickupLocation(4.720431, -74.041871, "George M.", "Ak. 15 #136-45, Bogotá, Colombia")
//                .setDropoffLocation(4.732878, -74.054728, "Home s", "Cl. 150 #53-28, Bogotá, Colombia")
//                .setProductId("a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d")
//                .build();

        // US
        RideParameters rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
                .setPickupLocation(37.775304, -122.417522, "Uber HQ", "1455 Market Street, San Francisco")
                .setDropoffLocation(37.795079, -122.4397805, "Embarcadero", "One Embarcadero Center, San Francisco") // Price estimate will only be provided if this is provided.
                .setProductId("a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d") // Optional. If not provided, the cheapest product will be used.
                .build();

        SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId("---")
                .setServerToken("---")
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .build();
        ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(config);

        RideRequestButtonCallback callback = new RideRequestButtonCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onRideInformationLoaded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ApiError apiError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }
        };

        requestButton = findViewById(R.id.uber_button_black);
        requestButton.setRideParameters(rideParams);
        requestButton.setSession(session);
        requestButton.setCallback(callback);
        requestButton.loadRideInformation();

    }
}
```

[image: Colombian address]
[image: US address]

Also, does SANDBOX really work with this SDK?